# Call webview methods from angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-app

I integrated a webview (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) in my angular Chrome App. Now I want to call reload() method of this webview. 
In normal javascript I would just get the webview by Id and call reload() method:

```
var webview = document.getElementById('my-webview');
webview.reload();
```

But how can I perform this by using angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `document.querySelector` method like so :

```
var webview = document.querySelector("my-webview");
```

But the Angular way should be to build a custom directive to access the DOM object.

Also don't forget to include the `webview` into the manifest.json permissions.

Here is the [Chrome Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_codelab8_webresources) for more info.

Comment: But is it an Angular way to get webview? Because Angular apps usually should not access DOM objects by ID at all

Comment: For me you should build a custom directive, but from the Chrome official [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_codelab8_webresources#controller), they are doing this way, so I just think it's up to you, adding this to my answer.